# angularJS in IntelliJ Idea 13 begin

Tags: angularjs

I use IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6. I try to compile a simple angular app. I make a new project - Static web. 
[image]
I just make 2 files - hello.html and controller.js.
hello.html:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller='HelloController'>
    <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

controller.js:

```
function HelloController($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
}
```

Right click on hello.html and Debug hello.html - or Open in Browser - Chrome and it shows `{{greeting.text}}, World.`

I installed in File - Settings - Plugins - AngularJS and NodeJS, also installed in Settings - Javascript - Libraries - AngularJS - pointing to the folder where I downloaded and unzipped the AngularJS.

What to do to see the "Hello World" in my browser?

Thanks!

Comment: what version of angular is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't creating a module with your app's name, and then you aren't registering your controller as an angular controller.
`<html ng-app>` Isn't doing anything without `<html ng-app="myApp">`.

myApp is the module that angular will look for when it is loaded. Once it finds that module it will look for anything else that it should register for that module.

Here is a working fiddle for what you're trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/gf1fa3sx/

The jist is that you need to declare your angular app with `angular.module('myApp', []);` before angular knows anything about what it should be doing. Then you need to declare your controller on that module with:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('HelloController', ['$scope',function($scope){
        //doStuff
    }]);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am taking an example from AngularJS - Brad Green and Shyam Seshadri - O’Reilly, I will learn about that later but now I want to make this code works, thanks!

Comment: I also tried with what you wrote in jsfiddle in a html and tried to execute the code and I get the same {{greeting.text}} World. I rechecked and I have the AngularJS and NodeJS plugins installed in Idea and angular.js v.1.3.15 in Settings-Javascript-Libraries.... :(

Answer (score 0):

you're missing Angular Library.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js

Good luck.

Comment: I still get {{greeting.text}}, World.     Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HelloController' is not a function, got undefined...
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
    at assertArg (angular.js:1587)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1597)
    at angular.js:8470
    at angular.js:7638
......
http://localhost:63342/angularApp/angular.js.map Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:63342/angularApp/controllers.js.map Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Mihaig You have to declare your main app on ng-app and you are using the old way to declare a controller, try this:
`var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('HelloController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 // Your code goes here
}]);`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:
**hello.html**:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="HelloController">
    <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**controller.js**:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
});
```

Thanks for your answers! hope my book won't put me in difficulties again :)